# Recorderjs doesn't upload records with longer than 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, recorder

I am using the recorderjs from https://github.com/addpipe/simple-recorderjs-demo

It works very fine but when I record an audio which is longer than 30 seconds, it doesn't upload it - How can I increase the max. filesize / audio length of recorderjs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe it is from backend check maximum upload file size

Comment: I found only the bufferlength but I don't understand how can I increase the audio length - Increasing the bufferlength from 4096 doesn't work

Comment: did you check maximum file size in php.ini

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please increase the size of `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` file.
This will fix your error. I have checked this on my local system, it's now uploading the larger files.

Thanks